# Which was the first true compatible MSX computer available in the market?

Tags: msx

I'm talking about true MSX computers, not MSX-ish, or partially compatible MSX computers (Spectravideo 318, I'm looking at you).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first MSX, the [Mitsubishi "ML-8000"](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_ML-8000), was released on October 21<sup>st</sup>, 1983. Four days later, the second MSX, the Sanyo "MPC-10", was released.

As you mentioned, the earlier SpectreVideo *claimed* to be MSX, [but wasn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSX#Similar_systems):

> The system most similar to the MSX was the Spectravideo SV-328 home computer (Spectravideo even claimed to be MSX compatible in advertisements before the actual launch of MSX systems, but it was in fact not completely compatible with the MSX).

I also feel it's worthwhile to include a picture of the first issue of MSX magazine (which for some reason features a cigar-smoking horse-man taking a bath in outer space):

[image: msx magazine]

<sub>Source (Japanese): http://weekly.ascii.jp/elem/000/000/179/179415/</sub>